# Extracting numbers from a string in Python

Tags: python, mysql

When I query my MySQL Database I get some extra characters that I don't want.
For example, instead of getting `165` I get `(165),` so, I tried the following in order to extract the number.

The problem is that instead of getting only the number, my code will print nothing, I can't find the reason. Any advice?

```
 arr = ''

    num = re.findall('\d+', arr)

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        database="diff"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM val ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    for x in myresult:
        arr = x        
        print(arr)
```

Comment: It seems that `myresult` is empty. Use a debugger or print statements to see which statements are being executed.

Comment: Also the first 2 lines are strange. num will be empty is not used. You maybe want to use the `compile` method in `re` to create a regex object. e.g. `pattern = re.compile("\d+")` and call `pattern.findall(x)` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most Python database connectors I've used give back tuples, you'd thus want to do:

```
for (x,) in myresult:
  print(x)
```

and you should get what you want

the docs I get suggest you can also just the cursor an iterable context manager, thus something like:

```
with mydb.cursor() as cur:
  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM val ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1")
  for (x,) in cur:
    print(x)
```

would be more idiomatic Python

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

something like this maybe:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="Bellini10-",
    database="diff"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM val ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

pattern = re.compile("\d+") 

for x in myresult:
    num = pattern.findAll(x)[0]       
    print(num)
```

Comment: I did not think about it. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
whitelist = set('0123456789')
num = ''.join(filter(whitelist.__contains__, arr))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help!